Object inside glass disappears at certain angles (Cycles)
Ive been working on this perfume bottle which has a glass BSDF node + transparent BSDF node but when looking at the object from the front, the inner "liquid" disappears. Why does this happen and how do I fix it? I have tried enabling Screen Space Refractions and changing the blend mode to Alpha Blend.
Side Angle

Front Angle

Glass Material

Perfume Liquid Material


Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

First thing I'd do is to go to the render options and increase the light path number of bounces, especially for volume, transmission and glossy.

Hi all, thanks for the help but I solved the issue by remaking the object awhile ago so I can't update on whether these suggestions worked or not, but will keep it in mind if I ever encounter this issue again
